# Return from void function

Tags: java, c++, return, language-features

Suppose a class exists as follows:

```
class Foo
{
    void do_after_something()
    {
    //some code here
    return;
    }

    void do_something()
    {
    //some code here
    return do_after_something(); //returning another (void) function
    }
};
```

JAVA is clearly opposed to something like the above, Borland C++ compiler issues a warning,
MS VC++ does not complain.

**My question is: Should returning from a void function be logically (theoretically) correct?**

```
return do_after_something();
```

as opposed to:

```
do_after_something();
return;
```

or **is it all implementation (compiler/language) dependent?**

Comment: It makes sense but not in Java or C++ for which returning void is denoted by a return without an argument. Anyway, you often see a void returning function as a procedure, i.e. a piece of code with a side effect, rather than a function that computes... no value.

Comment: Well yes, it's all language-dependent. You could easily imagine a language called Vava which is the same as Java except for this one thing.

Comment: Bear in mind that both these languages evolved from C which originally did not have `void`.  All functions were defined to return something (`int` by default), and you could assign a variable to the result of a function that never actually returned a value, giving you garbage.  On the other side, in Algol/Pascal/Ada, you write either a `procedure` (which does not return a value) or a `function` (which does).  You could say that a `void` function is an attempt to add a `procedure` to C to help prevent using garbage results of functions that don't return anything.

Comment: Glad this question was posted and already handled.  Just got into a kerfuffle with some people that were deriding me for thinking that return (void foo()) makes complete grammatical sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Philosophically, you *could* argue that returning the result of a `void`-returning function should be allowed but, sadly, that's not the case here, at least for Java.

It *is* valid for C++ however. If you try out the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void xyzzy(void) {}
void plugh(void) { return xyzzy();}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    plugh();
    return 0;
}
```

it will work fine.

This is detailed in `ISO C++11 6.6.3 /3`:

> A return statement with an expression of type `void` can be used only in functions with a return type of `cv void`; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

So it's really equally valid to argue that the Java way is correct if you think of `void` as not an actual type, but as an *absence* of something. For example, when you have:

```
int xyzzy(void) { return 42; }
```

in C, you're not forced to provide an argument of the correct (non-)type, such as with:

```
void plugh;
int twisty = xyzzy(plugh);
```

Ditto, the C++ way is correct as well, but in a different way  - the languages are what they are.

Comment: So it is the reality that even both theories are arguably correct, you get stuck with the choice of language-selected implementation. I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be allowed and considered valid in all languages. If you have a function whose return type is `void` and you return the result of an expression whose type is `void` (such as calling another `void` function), you've satisfied that constraint.

It's not considered useful to do this in C (though I think it may be allowed) because there's no reason to need it. Anytime you do:

```
return someVoidFn();
```

You can always translate that to:

```
someVoidFn();
return;
```

And get the exact same effect.

However, in C++ and Java, returning a `void` function does have a real use, and that's because those languages have *templates and generics*. Consider this (not very useful) Java class:

```
class NestedIdentity<T> {
  T run(int i, T value) {
    if (i == 0) return value;
    return run(i - 1);
  }
}
```

Its `run` method returns the value you pass to it, after calling itself a given number of times. I know, pointless, right? But the important part is that `T` *may be void*. You can do this:

```
NestedIdentity<Void> nest = new NestedIdentity<Void>();
nest(5, null);
```

And *this works*. In Java, `Void` (note the capitalization) instantiates a generic with a `void`-like type whose only value is `null`. If Java didn't allow returning a `void` expression in a `void` method, it would have to be a compile-time error to instantiate a generic with void.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 11 its possible and legal . You can return a void function from other void function.
Refrence The C++ Programming Language Chapter 12 , Bjarne Strousstrup